# Visualizing InnoDB's Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key

What would be the best way to get a visual representation of a group of MySQL tables' foreign key constraints? (other than drawing them out by hand)

Something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [postgresonline.com](http://www.postgresonline.com/images/journal/oo_relationships1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/)

Comment: Please describe what feature of the workbench to use

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFairy](http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/) should be able to produce a number of different graphical outputs (as well as translating between different dialects of SQL). You should be able to produce what you're looking for using those.